# PostgreSQL: Query runs fine in Prod but really slow in QA

Tags: postgresql, performance, query, postgresql-10

Postgres 10.4 dbs hosted in AWS environment. I have a query which joins two tables with many-to-many relationship. I learned while troubleshooting that Analyzer won't run until number of rows inserted are more than "autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor" number. i.e. .1 = 10% of records.

It all make sense that why query is so slow and "EXPLAIN VERBOSE" won't display correct plan until I run "Vacuum Analyze" manually on those two tables. BUT, the same logic won't apply in Production, where as soon as data added to those two tables, even though "autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor" hasn't met, "EXPLAIN VERBOSE" as well as query performance is just fine. I checked pg_stat_user_tables table and verified that neither AutoVacuum nor AutoAnalyzer has ran since the data insert. So, I am confused how things are working fine in PROD and why I don't see similar behavior in QA. Will appreciate any help. Thx.

Update:
Adding (ANALYZE, BUFFER), as asked by Vérace, and query kept running for 12 minutes before I stopped it.

So, I ran it with simple EXPLAIN VERBOSE with following output:

```
EXPLAIN VERBOSE
SELECT  b.id,  b.idindex, b.load_id
FROM public."Table_detail" AS b
where b.idindex in (
select idindex from public."Table_map"  where load_id = 1224
    ) and b.load_id = 1224 ;
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.73..12.78 rows=1 width=12)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
|  Output: b.id, b.idindex, b.load_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
|  Join Filter: (b.idindex = "Table_map".idindex)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
|  ->  Index Scan using index_detail1 on public."Table_detail" b  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=12)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
|        Output: b.id, b.load_id, b.prcdate, b.fullname, b.idindex, ...., b.created_at|
|        Index Cond: (b.load_id = 1224)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|  ->  Index Scan using bloomberg_returns_map1_loadid_index on public."Table_map"  (cost=0.43..4.45 rows=1 width=4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|        Output: "Table_map".id, "Table_map".load_id, "Table_map".idindex, "Table_map".mrktvalue, "Table_map".created_at                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|        Index Cond: ("Table_map".load_id = 1224)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Running the query without the EXPLAIN VERBOSE took 22 seconds with 1021 records returned.

Ran Vacuum analyze and here is EXPLAIN VERBOSE output afterward:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------|Hash Join  (cost=7894.02..8320.97 rows=1021 width=12)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
|  Output: b.id, b.idindex, b.load_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
|  Inner Unique: true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
|  Hash Cond: (b.idindex = "Table_map".idindex)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|  ->  Index Scan using index_detail1 on public."Table_detail" b  (cost=0.29..420.71 rows=1235 width=12)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|        Output: b.id, b.load_id, b.prcdate, b.fullname, b.idindex, ...., b.created_at|
|        Index Cond: (b.load_id = 1224)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|  ->  Hash  (cost=7890.65..7890.65 rows=246 width=4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
|        Output: "Table_map".idindex                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=7888.19..7890.65 rows=246 width=4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|              Output: "Table_map".idindex                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
|              Group Key: "Table_map".idindex                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
|              ->  Index Scan using map1_loadid_index on public."Table_map"  (cost=0.43..7420.28 rows=187166 width=4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|                    Output: "Table_map".idindex                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|                    Index Cond: ("Table_map".load_id = 1224)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And actual query ran in less than 2 seconds.

As mentioned in my original post, PRODUCTION doesn't require running VACUUM ANALYZE after adding a new load/inserting rows to above tables and it runs above query in less than a second.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Please provide the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for **both** queries... normally, the questions we get asked here are the other way around - i.e. QA is great and Prod is slow... Same machine - RAM, CPU, OS, Disk config... are the machines in the same datacentre? Same no. of records in the tables?

Comment: Almost forgot - and **very** important - the actual text of your query and the structure of its tables - use dbfiddle.uk - but put the same data here also!

Comment: Thanks  Vérace. Here is query which took several minutes to complete: 
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT  b.id,  b.idindex, b.load_id
FROM public."Table_detail" AS b
where b.idindex in (
select idindex from public."Table_map"  where load_id = 1223
    ) and b.load_id = 1223 ;

Comment: And after running Vacuum Analyze, took less than 2 seconds to complete: 
Query plan before and after updated above in main post:

Comment: Are all the vacuum settings the same?  autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor, as well the other settings, can be altered away from their defaults, either globally or for individual tables.

Comment: Thanks jjanes. Yes, they are pretty much identical. I actually played with several of them in QA and got to a point, where now anytime any data added to those tables, AutoAnalyze runs right away, but my question is why this is not required in PRODUCTION. Our main concern is over time, who knows, we may run into this problem in PRODUCTION, so wanted to understand it before hand.

Comment: >>Same machine - RAM, CPU, OS, Disk config... are the machines in the same datacentre? Same no. of records in the tables?
config wise both PROD and QA are very close. No. of records are far more (10 times) in PROD vs. QA. Which doesn't make sense that how this query works fine in PROD, with that many records, and not in QA, until Analyzer runs <Scratching my head>.